# Как приостановить js функцию click после получение ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть обычная кнопка button, которая запускает действие. И есть ajax запрос по функции on.click к этой кнопке. Как приостановить выполнение этой функции по click при успешном ajax запросе, не блокируя и не удаляя кнопку.

Пример кода:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $('document').ready(function(){
            var jump = '';

            $('#Button').on('click', function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {jump: jump},
                    success: function(data){    
                        //Тут должна быть остановка выполнения кода на 15 минут
                    }           
                });
            }); 
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: что значит _приостановить выполнение этой функции_?

Comment: _Тут должна быть остановка выполнения кода на 15 минут_ - какого именно кода?

Comment: @Grundy, этого кода $('#Button').on('click', function() {

Comment: В момент выполнения `success` этот код уже выполнился, поэтому непонятно как его можно приостановить.

Comment: @Grundy ну вот чтобы он еще раз мог выполниться только через 15 минут

Comment: через 15 минут после success или после нажатия? Стоит добавить это в вопрос, это более понятная формулировка чем та, что есть сейчас.

Comment: @Grundy через 15 минут после success. Я не знал, как точно сформулировать вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для отложенное выполнения кода можно воспользоваться методом [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

Что нужно сделать, чтобы обработчик не выполнялся в это время?

1. можно просто убрать обработчик данного события с элемента и навесить его снова по истечении времени
2. можно установить флаг, и проверять его каждый раз при запуске. Сбрасывать флаг, по истечении времени.

Например:

```
$('#Button').on('click', function btnClickHandler() {
    $('#Button').off('click', btnClickHandler); // убираем обработчик
    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {jump: jump},
        success: function(data){    
            //Добавляем обработчик снова через 15 минут.
            setTimeout(()=>$('#Button').on('click', btnClickHandler),15*60*1000)
        }           
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!